# kohana server image statically

Tags: php, image, kohana

i have a kohana based website and i want to serve images statically (not through a controller).
if i am giving the real path to the image:

```
 <img src="/media/ceva.jpg" alt='<?= $product->name ?>' title="<?= $product->name ?>" />
```

i keep getting a route error:

```
Kohana_Request_Exception [ 0 ]: Unable to find a route to match the URI: media/ceva.jpg
```

is there any way to serve the images statically (not through an object) in kohana ?
thanks!

Comment: Yes, but that depends on what webserver you are using. If it's Apache or nginx, you could do this with [url_rewrite module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html). IIS also have .htaccess support, but never used it personally, so can't guarantee it is working.

Comment: You will probably need to change the rewrite rule (.htaccess). If you have that can you post it here?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with Kohana but usually the desired way to serve static files is configuring your webserver in a way that the application/framework never sees those request.

If you are using Apache, you can simply use `Alias /media /path/to/your/media/folder` in the VirtualHost.

Answer (score 0):

My personal preference is to setup a method in URL class to serve valid static content URLs. Something like:

```
public static function media($path)
{
    $media_path = Kohana::$config->load('whatever');

    return URL::site($media_path.$path);
}
```

Of course, modify this to your needs.

The problem you're experiencing is caused by nonexisting file on that location, not an Apache rule. Kohanas' apache rules allow all files to be accessed directly, the security check is defined in each php file separately.